# Excel - Is it possible to overwrite an other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want for exemple :

In cell A1 the date with =TODAY() - I want to have the output (dd/mm/yyyy for exemple) directly paste into A3 (and the next day A3 keeps the same value)

Thanks in advance, I've been looking the whole day for this but I can't seem to find... (french btw)

Edit : I forgot to precise, it would be better this being a function

Comment: Copy past the value only?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to tell... It should be a function :/

Comment: A function will not do it.  Functions are live and will change when the value in A1 changes.  You will need vba or simple copy paste the values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will search more about the VBA thing thanks Scott

Comment: Look in to `Worksheet Change()` and set up a macro that detects if the changed cell was `A3`, and if so, then you can just do `Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value`.

Comment: A function produces a value for the cell it is in.  It can't put a value into another cell.  It also can't replace itself with a fixed value.